# PHP session and ajax with curl request in rest

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rest, session

my question is about session and how to store variable to check in php script

below is my ajax code

```
 $('#login').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "home.php",
        data: $('#login-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        },
      });
  });
```

and here is my code for php session which in a separate file

```
 session_start();
$curl = curl_init();

$token = base64_encode("{$_POST['username']}:{$_POST['password']}");
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    echo "login success".$_SESSION['token'];
}
else {
    die("fail");
}
```

that's the beginning of my script, what i want to do is to check if the token been stored with same value in both html and php files.
for some reason the token variable has a value regardless of whether the user login or not, and when he does the value in html file is ok but in the php is not stored the same. 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"the token variable has a value"_: yes, because you set any value a line before! Where do you test if username and pwd match?

Comment: the test done using rest api, but what i wanted to test if the value of token in the script is the same as the value in the html file hence i am echoing the value to make sure it is correct. @Jeff

Comment: Yeah, your code is fatally flawed. You use isset to check if $_SESSION['token'] is set...but you set it a line above so this ALWAYS returns true. You used base64 encode with a format of {user}:{password}...even if those two variables were empty, the colon gets encoded. I'd explain in detail your goal because It's hard to understand as it is. This doesn't even appear to be a login script as there's no checks for authentication.

Comment: @Thomas, I see what you mean, if i change the order it will fail as it didn't return true (the semi colon in this case hasn't been encoded), now i understand why is it different from the html file when i check it there. what i want to do is for the user to enter their details and then check for authentication (basic) by sending a curl request to rest api, and if success the user can proceed

Comment: If you're just looking to do the ajax check, just do that then. Reply with a json_encode'd array with true or false. Check the variables against a database, if successful THEN set the token. Authentication classes exist, so may look into that instead of reinventing the wheel as they can be difficult to secure sometimes.